# Why does OAuth have two separate tokens (access and refresh)?

Tags: oauth2

In the OAuth2 protocol, two kind of tokens are used:

access_token: Granted by authorization server, used by resources servers to decide whether access should be granted for the resource

refresh_token: Granted by authorization server, used by authorization server to grant new access_tokens
The purpose of this separation is to enable scalability:

Resource servers can verify access tokens without negotiating with authorization servers.
Authorization servers are only used for granting access_tokens.
Resource servers can implement immediate access_token revocation with backlists, and due to the access_token expiration window this blacklist does not need to grow indefinitely.

The purpose of these tokens are clear, but I wonder about the reason of having these roles encapsulated into two separate physical tokens. Would it be possible to put all the information into a single token that could be used both as an access and a refresh token as well:

- Authorization server grants a token (that encapsulates a session id)
- Client uses the token to access resource servers
- Token eventually expires, resource servers will reject requests after that time
- Client sends the token back to the authorization server, auth server checks if the session is still alive based on the encapsulated session id
- Authorization server returnes a new token (with the same session id)
- Client can access the resource servers again

Is there any potential security issue with the flow above?

Comment: An "obvious" answer (and perhaps the correct one; I don't know enough to be certain) is you only send to each type of server what it needs: you don't waste bandwidth endlessly sending (encapsulated) refresh tokens to resource servers. A "pre-question" I'd ask: in what way do you think having one combined token would be _better_ than two separate tokens? What problem(s) would doing so solve?

Comment: @TripeHound  Our goal is to implement our authentication layer inspired by the idead of OAuth2. We intend to simplify our clients as much as possible: it is easier to manage a single token than two separate one. Everything that we store in the token should be readable by both servers (auth, resource). As we aim to send the token as a cookie, having two separate cookie would require more bandwidth.

Comment: As I said, I'm not an expert, but to a first approximation, the info in one combined token would, I think, be roughly the sum of the two individual tokens, so one (combined) token in one cookie should be about the same as two tokens in two cookies. If bandwidth _is_ a concern, keeping two tokens, and only sending the appropriate one to the appropriate server (as OAuth2 does) would seem the way to go. **Obligatory InfoSec warning** re. "_implement our authentication layer inspired by_"... the strong advice on here is never design / implement your own security scheme: use an existing one.